# When reading back asynchronously from compute shaders in Unity, can I reset buffer halfway?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compute-shader

Hope there will be nothing confusing in what I'm going to talk about, because my mother tongue is not English and my grammar is poor:p

I'm working on a mipmap analyzing tool which need to calculate with pixels from the render texture. Here's a part of the C# code:

```
    private IEnumerator CSGroupColor(RenderTexture rt, GroupColor[] groupColors)
    {
        var outputBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(groupColors.Length, 8);
        csKernelID = cs.FindKernel("CSGroupColor");
        
        cs.SetTexture(csKernelID, "rt", rt);
        cs.SetBuffer(csKernelID, "groupColorOut", outputBuffer);
        cs.Dispatch(csKernelID, rt.width / 8, rt.height / 8, 1);
        
        var req = AsyncGPUReadback.Request(outputBuffer);
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => req.done);
        
        req.GetData<GroupColor>().CopyTo(groupColors);
        foreach (var color in groupColors)
        {
            if (!m_staticsDatas.TryGetValue(color.groupindex, out var vl))
                continue;
            if (color.value > 0)
                vl.allColors.Add(color.value);
        }
    }
```

And what I want to implement next, is to make every buffer smaller(e.g.with a length of 4096), like we usually do in other asynchronous communications. Maybe I can pass the first buffer to CPU right away when it's full, and then replace it with the second buffer, and so on.

As I see it, using SetBuffer() again after req.done must be permitted to make that viable. I have been finding on Internet all day for a sample usage, but still found nothing.

Is there anyone who would give some help? Thx very much.